# setting expiry on one value within a jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using a jQuery cookie to set 3 value say `x`,`y` and `z` and I want `z` to expire after 365 days but not expire `x` and `y`.

```
$.cookie("MyTestCookie", xyz, { expires: 999999 });
```

I have split the values using:

```
var xVal =  my_cookie_value.substring(0);
var yVal =  my_cookie_value.substring(1);
var zVal =  my_cookie_value.substring(2);

$.cookie("MyTestCookie", zVal, { expires: 365 });
```

Thakyou in advance

Comment: What is the issue you're having? Your code should work as it is, assuming you place `y` and `x` in a different cookie to `z`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think thats the problem - the cookie names are the same `MyTestCookie` ...

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is

```
$.cookie("MyTestCookie", xyz, { expires: 999999 });  
$.cookie("MyTestCookie", zVal, { expires: 365 });
```

this is just replacing the first cookie with the second and updates the value and expiration as the names (`MyTestCookie`) are the same

What you can do is this :

```
$.cookie("X-MyTestCookie", xVal, { expires: 99999 }); 
$.cookie("Y-MyTestCookie", yVal, { expires: 99999 }); 
$.cookie("Z-MyTestCookie", zVal, { expires: 365 });
```

notice the cookie names are different (`X-MyTestCookie`, `Y-MyTestCookie` and `Z-MyTestCookie`) - this places the values in different cookies ...

or

```
$.cookie("MyTestCookie", xVal + "%" + yVal, { expires: 99999 }); 
$.cookie("Z-MyTestCookie", zVal, { expires: 365 });
```

In the first line the `%` character is used as a delimiter to separate the values - you then need to split the values when you get the cookie.

Comment: thanks guys but the problem is i cannot add more cookies with the project i'm on - its just the one cookie MyTestCookie which needs to have the 'dual expiry'

Comment: @user1010701 A cookie has an expiry date - it cannot have multiple expiry dates